# how to change src attribute of image through input type file in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to change the source attribute of image through input file type. If i choose an image in my system that image should display immediately in image holder div without any database, i'm using static only i don't have database and all. if it is not possible without database then i want to save that image in my local image folder and then display in image holder. Is it possible with angular?? I'm learning angular can any one help with this.

this is what i have written::

```
<div class="image_holder">
   <img ng-src="{{img_src}}" width="" height="" alt=""/>
   <input type="file" ng-model="changeimageSrc" 
   onchange="angular.element(this).scope().changeImage()" ng- 
  change="changeImage()"/>
   </div>



 $scope.changeImage = function(){                  
   $scope.img_src = '../images/' + $scope.changeimageSrc;
   alert($scope.changeimageSrc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .jpg or any other file extension after changeImageSrc like this

$scope.img_src = '../images/' + $scope.changeimageSrc + ‘.jpg’
   alert($scope.changeimageSrc);